# Operator precedence in C (!= and |)

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I recently corrected a bug in a C program where I had:

```
if (foobar != FOO | BAR | BAZ)
```

The correct code is

```
if (foobar != (FOO | BAR | BAZ))
```

According to the [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) it is clear that `!=` has precedence over `|`.

My question is why it is like this and not the other way around? From my experience I will often use either `a == b || a == c` or `d == (a | b | c)`, but never `a == b | c == d`.

What is the logic behind this choice?

Comment: `foobar != FOO | BAR | BAZ` is equivalent to `(foobar != FOO) | BAR | BAZ` because prececence of `!=` is higher than `|`. Use it if it is what you want.

Comment: Because one is an binary arithmetic operator (`|`) and thus belongs to same level as other arithmetic operators, and the other is a logic operator (`||`).

Comment: Because that's how the language designers decided to do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hopefully the language designers think before deciding, I am asking about the reason of their choice.

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194635/why-do-bitwise-operators-have-lower-priority-than-comparisons

Comment: Consider `(foobar == FOO | foobar == bar)`.  Imagine the hilarity that ensues when this doesn't work as expected, because the `==` isn't higher precedence.

Comment: Surely there is a duplicate for this on SO. This question along with that Dennis Ritchie quote has been posted many times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has historical reasons, quote from Dennis Ritchie:

> “Early C had no separate operators for & and && or | and ||. Instead
>   it used the notion (inherited from B and BCPL) of ‘truth-value
>   context': where a Boolean value was expected, after ‘if‘ and ‘while‘
>   and so forth; the & and | operators were interpreted as && and || are
>   now; in ordinary expressions, the bit-wise interpretations were used.
>   It worked out pretty well, but was hard to explain. (There was the
>   notion of ‘top-level operators’ in a truth-value context.) “The
>   precedence of & and | were as they are now.
>
> Primarily at the urging of
>   Alan Snyder, the && and || operators were added. This successfully
>   separated the concepts of bit-wise operations and short-circuit
>   Boolean evaluation. However, I had cold feet about the precedence
>   problems. For example, there were lots of programs with things like:
>   if (a==b & c==d) …
>
> “In retrospect it would have been better to go
>   ahead and change the precedence of & to higher than ==, but it seemed
>   safer just to split & and && without moving & past an existing
>   operator.”

Answer (score 0):

Dennis Ritchie's [Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) covers this and other curious historical artifacts.

Basically, originally the language did not have the `&&` and `||` operators -- just `&` and `|`, so you *would* write things like `a == b | c == d`.  The precedence rules were designed based on that.

Later, the short ciruiting operators were added, but the precedence of the old operators was not revised.